# trying to parse event log xml to get targetusername, logon type, timecreated columns

Tags: xml, parsing, powershell, events, logging

I am at a loss trying to get my script below to output a targetusername and logon type column because of how property is stored in the `$XMLEntryobject`. I receive the following error when running my code below;

> Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type
>   "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "This document already has a
>   'DocumentElement' node."

```
$ComputerName='fod71247'

$XMLFilter = @"
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
    *[System[(EventID=4624 or EventID=4634 or EventID=4625)
    and
    TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;='2015-10-30T12:00:00:000Z' and @SystemTime&lt;='2015-10-31T00:00:00:000Z']]
    and
    EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName'] and (Data='c660503')]
    and
    EventData[Data[@Name='LogonType'] and (Data='7' or Data='2')]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
"@

$Events=Get-WinEvent -computername $ComputerName -FilterXml $XMLFilter 

foreach ($Event in $Events) {
    $EventXML += [XML]$Events.ToXML()

}

foreach ($XMLEntry in $EventXML) {
    foreach ($Property in $XMLEntry.Event.EventData.Data) {
        if ($Property.Name -eq "TargetUserName" -and $Property.Name -eq "TimeCreated" -and $Property.Name -eq "LogonType" -and $Property.'#text' -ne ($ComputerName + "$")) {
            Write-Host $Property.'#text'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give us a more detailed error message? You can retrieve more error details using `$error[0] | fl * -f`

Comment: here is a more detailed error.  

Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node."
At line:22 char:2
+     $EventXML += [XML]$Events.ToXML()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument

Comment: `[XML]$Events.ToXML()` should be `[XML]$Event.ToXML()` (no **S**)

Comment: i changed the code to [XML]$Event.ToXML() and now i do not receive an error, but i receive no data either.

Comment: what if you try to extract the data only ?  `[xml]$ev=$event.toXML();$EventXML += $ev.event.eventdata.data`

Comment: when i only return target username property, i get back targetusername only for each entry, but when i try to select timecreated and logontype i get no data returned. Do i need to change how i am trying to pull back, timecreated, logotype columns? i would like to export the data to csv if possible

Comment: you cant have one property that satisfy your conditions : `$Property.Name -eq "TargetUserName" -and $Property.Name -eq "TimeCreated" ....` try with `-or` instead

Comment: I tried the -or and i now get back the targetusername and logontype but under one column. Would i be able to seperate the data into seperate columns?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that create a psobject to store some event properties

```
$result=$computername|%{
        "Checking $_ NPS " |write-verbose

        icm -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
            $server=$env:computername
            Get-WinEvent -FilterXml "<QueryList><Query Id='0' Path='Security'><Select Path='Security'>*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=6273) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 3600000]]]</Select></Query></QueryList>" -maxevent 100 |
            %{
                $o="dummy"|select server,machinename,MAC #quickly create an object with server,machinename and mac properties
                $o.server=$server
                [xml]$ev=$_.toXML();$ev.event.eventdata.data | %{ #parse the event data to extract useful infos
                    if($_.name -eq "SubjectMachineName") {$o.machinename=$_."#text"}
                    elseif($_.name -eq "CallingStationID") {$o.mac=$_."#text"}
                } 
            }
            $o #return the created object
        }
    }
    $result |select machinename,mac,server -uniq
```